# VS2013 for windows and typescript

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am doing a windows app. It was developing with cordova and js but now there on part with typescript. I can write everything in typescript and later on through "cmd" I execute tsc file.ts and all works but .... when I try to compile the project I add the js files and I get always this errors:

```
APPHOST9626: A direct reference to resource file ms-appx://
```

Why? I think that I have to add the references and I was follow this tutorial http://www.timmykokke.com/2014/04/enabling-typescript-compilation-in-windows-store-apps/ but without successful.

Thanks in advance!